# How can I get the rt.exec to run the command line in a different folder instead of the root folder

Tags: java

I would like to create a folder call pythoncode within my root directory and have  rt.exec * run within this folder so my *.py files can be in a seperate folder.
My test code

```
void test()
{
Runtime rt;
rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String line = null; 

try{
Process pr = rt.exec("python chart.py");

InputStreamReader mInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( pr.getInputStream());
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( mInputStreamReader );

    while ( (line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(line);
}    
 catch( Exception ex)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "Abort", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);         
}

} // end methed
```

Comment: Did you look at the Javadoc? There are multiple versions of `exec()` and one of them lets you specify the current directory.  Please do your research before posting questions here.

Comment: You want a `ProcessBuilder`, it lets you set the working directory.